# VBA: worksheet row overflow error 'Run-time error '6' Overflow using worksheets().Range

Tags: excel, vba, row, overflow, worksheet

I have a vba program that is filling a sheet with the results of a simulation.  One line of code is:

```
Dim RunCounter As Integer
Dim Margin (250,000, 5) as Variant

Worksheets("Optimization").Range("s", & RunCounter + 2) = Margin(Runcounter, 0)
```

When RunCounter gets to a value of 32766 so the row total is 32768, I get an overflow error

> Run-time error '6':   Overflow

I am not sure why I am getting this since excel allows many more rows.

Any ideas?

I don't know what to try.  Since Worksheets is not dimensioned, I am not sure what to do

Comment: `32767` is the max value for an `Integer` - Use a `Long` instead - `Dim RunCounter As Long`

Comment: Also, don't use a comma as thousands separator in VBA (you've got two commas in your DIM statement).

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it.  I was confused because it wasn't giving me the error when it incremented RunCounter. Just when I added the 2.